# call stack when Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, callstack, backtrace

I code this(backtrace.hpp) to show the call stack when my program crashed like segmentation fault.

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const std::map<int, std::string> signals_map =
{
    {SIGSEGV, "SIGSEGV"},
    {SIGABRT, "SIGABRT"},
    {SIGINT, "SIGINT"},
    {SIGFPE, "SIGFPE"},
    {SIGILL, "SIGILL"},
    {SIGSYS, "SIGSYS"},
    {SIGBUS, "SIGBUS"},
    {SIGIOT, "SIGIOT"},
    {SIGTRAP, "SIGTRAP"},
};

class Backtrace
{
private:
    static void ExceptionHandler(int signum, siginfo_t* info, void* ctx){
        int nptrs;
        void *buffer[1024];
        char **strings;

        nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 1024);
        strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
        if (strings == NULL) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::cout<<std::endl<<"****** Crash Backtrace signal: "<<signals_map.at(signum)<<"******"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
        for (int i = 2; i < nptrs; i++) {
            std::cout<<"     "<<strings[i]<<std::endl;
        }

        free(strings);
        signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
    }
public:
    Backtrace(){
        struct sigaction action;
        sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
        action.sa_sigaction = &ExceptionHandler;
        action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        for (const auto& signals: signals_map)
        {
            if (0 > sigaction(signals.first, &action, NULL))
            {
                std::cout<<"sigaction failed:"<<signals.second<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    ~Backtrace(){}
};
```

Usually, it is usefull. But sometimes, I just got info like:
$ /bin/sh: line 1:  6571 Segmentation fault
There is no backtrace output.
Why does this happen?

In my code, I use the backtrace.hpp like this:

```
#inlcude "backtrace.hpp"
int main(){
    Backtrace b;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You normally can't do anything with a segmentation fault, as your process gets killed immediately.

Comment: When the OS gets a segmentation fault signal, it usually terminates it directly instead of giving back control to a process that exhibits erroneous or potentially malicious behavior. This is expected behavior from a security standpoint, and also there's no way for the OS to assume the process will behave as expected with memory corruption even if it's not malicious.

Comment: Since I can not expected the os to call my function to print the call stack. Is there any 
effective way to show the call stack?

Comment: Some signals can't be caught by your program - in which case your program will terminate immediately and your backtracing code will never be executed.   Also bear in mind that, at best, your code shows the trace for the code where the signal is caught, not the code that causes it  (e.g.  the actual offending code may overwrite some program data, some other unrelated code may [much] later access the overwritten data and then perform some action that results in a signal from the OS].

Comment: @BigFaceBoy No, the OS is the first handler and the one that terminates the process. You can use custom allocators that memory map large regions and do runtime checks to catch buffer overflows and similar before the signal, but even that isn't a clear cut. For example Valgrind and other memory address sanitizers.

Comment: Within the context of an exception handler, there are some things you cannot do there.  Like I/O (with a few specific APIs as exceptions).  Or malloc/free.

Comment: You can always read the generated core dump into your debugger and get the stack trace there.

Comment: Dose someone know that why crash can always print the call stack in Android

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

There are very few functions you can legally use in a signal handler (the [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) ones).

The `malloc` and `free` are not safe, `backtrace_symbols()` calls `malloc()`, and using `std::cout` is simply *asking* for trouble.

It's possible to print the crash stack trace *fairly* reliably, but that requires *a lot* of care (and quite a [lot of code](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/debugging/symbolize_elf.inc)), and you aren't careful *at all*.

If your crash is happening due to heap corruption (as many crashes are), calling `backtrace_symbols()` may crash, deadlock or simply fail. If either of these happens, your code would fail to print anything.